# Stacking masked divs' contents with SVG

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm currently stuck with trying to create stacked `<div>` elements where the top-level `<div>` has its content masked, in React (although this is likely unimportant other than for SVG element notation).

Given two responsively-styled `<div>`s — A and B — both containing an `<img>` each, where B is absolutely positioned above A, I would like to apply an inline, arbitrary SVG mask to `<div>` B so that it partially exposes the content of `<div>` A below it.

Visually, I am trying to achieve something like this...

Two `<div>`s, absolutely positioned so that they stack on top of one another:
[image]

An inline `<svg>`'s content:
[image]

...Is used as a mask against `<div>` B so that it produces this effect:
[image]

I want to avoid using `clip-path`s as they have [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path), and am wondering if there is a way of achieving this effect with a less complex approach. It is also important that I'm able to position the `<img>` elements within the `<div>`s, and add more elements if needed — rather than just setting a background `mask-image` on the `<svg>`.

Is there a way of doing this that does not rely on SVG `<mask>` or `<clipPath>` elements? And if not, is there a way to embed more than just an `<img>` (via SVG `<image>`) in the SVG mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I'm using images, since this is what you want. I would have used background images. Also I'm using `clip-path` to clip the second div. In the first example I'm using an svg path for this.

```css
#a,
#b {
  outline: 1px solid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#b{
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip); 
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="a">
  <img width="300" height="300" src ="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="b">
  <img  width="300" height="300"  src ="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppyBeagle300.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
           <path d="M0,0.9 L0.3,.6 .4,.75  .6,.3 .75,.5 1,.1 1,1 0,1z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Alternatively you can use the `polygon` function.

```css
#a,
#b {
  outline: 1px solid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#b{
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 90%, 30% 60%, 40% 75%, 60% 30%, 75% 50%, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 90%, 30% 60%, 40% 75%, 60% 30%, 75% 50%, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="a">
  <img width="300" height="300" src ="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="b">
  <img  width="300" height="300"  src ="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppyBeagle300.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, even though this does use `clip-path`, this works really well for now :) Appreciate the snippet also!